# Unexpected EOF in HTTPS request

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest

I have the following function that sends xml using Https request

```
public WebResponse SendXmlPost(string url, string xml)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    request.Method = "POST";

    if (this.UseBasicAuthentication)
    {
        string usernamePassword = this.Login + ":" + this.Password;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));
        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(this.Login, this.Password);
        request.Credentials = cred;
    }

    if (this.desactivateCertificateChecking)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };
    }

    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); //error occurs here

    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    return response;
}
```

When i call this method, I have and "unexpected EOF" exception:

```
System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +7067555
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +116
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +123
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +7243141
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) +217
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData) +376
```

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the UTF8 encoding. By default, UTF-8 encoding adds a BOM (ByteOrderMark), and your ContentLength is out of sync with the data being transmitted. Try creating a UTF8 encoding without BOM (use another overload) and it should fix the problem.

Additionally, I would not add the Basic auth header myself. I would just set the crdentials on the request and let HttpWebRequest do the auth for me.